# How do I use Angularjs's ng-style to change the background every 3 seconds?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-style

Still learning angular here and could use some help after much research.

Very simple example I have going, I am simply applying the ng-style directive to the body to change the background as such

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController as main" ng-style="***need help here***">
```

controller

```
 angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

.controller('mainController', function() {

    // set the view model as this scope
    var vm = this

    vm.slides = [
       { images: 'assets/imgs/blurred-highway.jpg' },
       { images: 'assets/imgs/night-square.jpg' }
    ]

})
```

I have not had much luck with the ui.bootstrap carousel, thus I am looking to implement something even simpler; just want the full-screen background to change every 3 seconds infinitely cycling through the slides collection (will eventually have 6-7 photos), no additional controls needed.

help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You just have to make use of [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).
Note that for the sake of the example, I replace your images with both colors: blue and red.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController as main" ng-style="{'background-color': main.slide}">
   //content
  </body>
```

Here's the Javascript code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($interval) {

    // set the view model as this scope
    var vm = this

    var slides = [
       'blue' ,
       'red'
    ];

    vm.slide = slides[0]; 
    $interval(function(){
      if(vm.slide == slides[0])
          vm.slide = slides[1];
      else
          vm.slide = slides[0];
    }, 3000, 0);


});
```

Here's the corresponding [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qGB9ywPwMABAS3uTALDA?p=preview).

Thus, you just have to replace the colors and `background-color` by your images and `background-image`